# Get (localized) payment source registration errors directly from Stripe Elements

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm trying to localize error messages occurring during the registration of payment sources and am looking for an easy way out: Is it possible to let stripe do the complete validation of a card directly via the stripe.js api and get a localized error message as a result before I send the token to my server (and then to stripe)? Some errors *are* caught by the card element, e.g. an incorrect checksum (CC No. `4242424242424241`) and returned localized by the js library, giving me hope that I have just missed the right configuration option.

Background: One of our customers triggered a "Your card has insufficient funds." error during card *registration* (we only issue a charge at a later time) and we weren't able to show a helpful error message because we didn't have a localization for this error and I can't find a complete list of possible error (codes).

Comment: Sibling question regarding localization in the backend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441420/how-can-i-get-localized-error-messages-from-stripe

Comment: Have you found a satisfying answer? Is the Stripe API localized now?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this your other question as well, but this gem might be useful for you here: https://github.com/ekosz/stripe-i18n

You can also find the API errors here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors

Comment: While it is certainly a start, it only provides translations for a very limited subset of the possible errors: https://github.com/ekosz/stripe-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml